# Are ASP.NET MVC5 and ASP.NET Web API 2 compatible with VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I have VS2012 and may not be able to upgrade it to VS2013 just yet, I want to know whether I can use it to build ASP.NET MVC 5.0 and ASP.NET Web API 2 projects?
From the ASP.NET web site, it seems that VS2013 is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use vs2012. Check this [Web Tools 2013.1 for Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Why doesn't this get mentioned on asp.net website? Odd.